# Linq to SQL issue

Tags: sql, linq

I create a class library add a linq to SQL class and drag some tables.
Create another class library add a ref to the above project and create a brief function to GetCustomers (dim query = from c in customers select c return c.toList)
I then add a Vb .Net web app and add a ref to the second class library created and call the GetCustomers method. 
I got an error message telling me to add a reference to class which contains the linq to SQL data model which doesn't seem right.

How could I separate these layers correctly? I would appreciate and articles or any code in Vb .Net.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the exact error message, and perhaps a code sample that demonstrates the separation and references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data classes are defined in the Linq to SQL class library, the web app needs a reference to it in order to know what those classes are.

To truly separate the layers, you would need to [use the Linq to SQL classes to create separate transfer objects](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/09/best-practices-for-using-linq-in-your-data-access-layer/) in the second class library.

A tool like [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) can be really helpful there.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. Could anyone confirm if the below is correct?

1. Create a class add Linq To SQL class. This is the DAL.
2. Add another class library project and mimic the database tables by adding properties etc. Add reference to the project in step 1.This is the DTO.
3. Add another class library project and add all my methods to retrieve what data i need. I add a ref to the project in step 2. This is the Business layer.
4. Add a web project with a ref to the project created in step 3 and call methods as appropriate.

Thanks

Comment: @Jupiter - I'm not sure that your DTO class library would need to reference the DAL class library.  The business layer class library would just reference both the DTO and DAL layer libraries and handle the translation from DAL classes to DTO classes.  This way your DTO class library can be completely independant of the DAL classes.

Answer (score 1):

Your LINQ to SQL models need to be explicitly referenced in order to use them. You can't infer a reference through another reference.

A way around this is using DTO's and view models.

- In this scenario the Web app calls a repository in the middle layer
- middle layer calls data layer for entity
- data layer gives middle layer the entity
- middle layer translates entity into a Data Transfer Object and returns that to the web app
- web app uses data transfer object to communicate state of entity to middle layer
- web app translates DTO to view models for presentation.

This is a pretty general overview. Basically each layer has its own idea for what the data looks like and has a contract with the other layer on how to translate. Other people can explain it better than I can. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430014/N-Tier-Architecture-and-Tips) is a pretty decent article on N-Tier architecture.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your function might be returning the values as the type List(Of Customers) - in which case the Customers type is defined in your first class library.

Assuming your projects are called "Data", "Business", and "UI", if you do not want to have your UI project reference the Data class library, the business project is going to have to copy or present the results from data into a form that is defined in business so that UI can use it.  Otherwise, UI will have to reference Data just for the type definitions even if it ultimately only makes calls against business.